# ODE on Circle and torus

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

How can we define an ODE on unit Circle $S^1=x^2+y^2=1$ and torus $S^1*S^1$? Every ODE on circle must satisfies $x \dot{x}+y \dot{y}=0$. Therefor $\dot{x}=-y , \dot{y}=x$ is a system on Circle. but this system has $x^2+y^2=r$ as a general solution. Since it is the Hamiltonian and complete system as well. So what are ODE on circle and torus?

Comment: The solution to $\dot{x}=-y,\dot{y}=x$ is not the actual circle itself. It is the clockwise path around the circle with angular velocity identically equal to $1$. Other ODEs can traverse the circle with different velocity. Same deal with the torus except that on the torus there are two angles to play with.

Comment: Write down some one variable function that traverses the circle or torus and determine the ODE that it satisfies.

Comment: Thanks, Copper. May you give me an example.? I didn't understand the  "variable function that traverses the circle or torus and determines the ODE that it satisfies". Please clarify ODEs on circle and torus with some examples. or refer me to a book or papers

Comment: Take two indpendent ODEs for one on the torus.

Answer (score 1):

You would profit a lot from seeing an equation on the circle as one of the form
$$
\theta'=f(\theta)
$$
for some $1$-periodic function $f$. Taking $x=\cos \theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$ we get
$$
x'=-\theta'\sin\theta\quad\text{and}\quad y'=\theta'\cos\theta,
$$
which is the same as
$$
x'=-f(\theta)y\quad\text{and}\quad y'=f(\theta)x.
$$
You can in fact write $f(\theta)$ using $x$ and $y$ since $\tan\theta=y/x$ (the problem with $x=0$ is that $S^1$ is a manifold and in fact we need at least two charts to cover it; if you prefer, saying this in another manner: $\theta$ clearly is not globally defined although $\theta'$ is). So we can rewrite the former equations in the form
$$
x'=-g(x,y)y\quad\text{and}\quad y'=g(x,y)x.\tag1
$$
Conversely, for any equation of this form we have $xx'+yy'=0$ and so it defines and equation on the circle.

Summing up, **we have a differential equation on the circle if and only if it has form (1) for some function $g$**.

Similarly, any equation on the torus is of the form
$$
x'=f(x,y),\quad y'=g(x,y)
$$
for some functions $f$ and $g$ that are $1$-periodic in both variables.

Comment: Thank you so much John! :).  I have 3 questions related to your explanation.  Question 1)  why $f(\theta)$ and $f(x,y),  g(x,y)$ must be 1- periodic for both circle and torus? I mean why do you consider $1$.

Comment: Question 2) The torus is a two-dimensional manifold. But it is in $\mathbb{R}^4$.  I don't understand why $x'=f(x,y),   y'=g(x,y)$ determine an ODE on torus. I think we need to define $4$ equations. Since it is the product of two circles.

Comment: Question 3) I define an ODE on torus  :   $x'=-g(x,y)y,     ~~~~  y'=g(x,y)x, ~~~~      z'= -h(z,w) w,   ~~~~   w'=h(z,w) z$. It is correct or not?

Comment: I don't quite follow your questions: If you understand what I detailed about the circle, surely you also understand what I mentioned about the torus since it is exactly the same. Sure, you can consider any period that you want. But if you have other questions, you need to ask them separately.

Comment: Thanks again John!

Answer (score 0):

Any ODE of the form $\dot{x} = f(x,y), \, \dot{y} = g(x,y)$ with $xf(x,y) + yg(x,y) = 0$ has only solutions with the property $x^2 + y^2 = const.$.

So choose any smooth $f_0: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, set $f(x,y) = f_0(x,y) y, \,  g(x,y) = - f_0(x,y)x$, and you have such a system.

Comment: Thank you Hans. As you said it has solutions $x^2+y^2=constant$ that we have infinite circles, not just unit circle. It is correct to consider it as an ODE just on the unit circle?

Comment: And how about ODE on a torus?